# Copy styles of a table using jspdf-autoTable and jspdf

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a table with different colors and each color represents something, when I convert my table with jspdf-autotable, it creates the table but skips the styles, can I copy the styles too.

TIA

```
let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
pdf.autoTable({html: '#table'});
pdf.save('tabley.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `useCss` option. It copies over some basic styles.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Bengstsson can you please tell me how to use it, I cannot find it in jspdf-autotable docs.

Comment: I used the `useCss` property to true in options but it only copies the styles in first column, looks like I have to create different table with jspdf